# integer to roman numeral, cannot use def. function

Tags: python

I have a homewrok assignment to convert a roman numeral to an integer. I am stuck at the part of the actual "formula" to change the roman numerals to integers and subtract/add them to the next one. We have not learned the "def" function yet so I cannot use that. Here is the code I have so far. I am just three weeks into coding so it is probably not very good..

```
DictOfRomanNumerals = {"I":1, "II":2, "III":3, "IV":4, "V":5, "IX":9, "X":10,
                       "XL":40, "L":50, "XC":90, "C":100, "CD":400, "D":500,
                       "CM":900, "M":1000}

UserInput = input("Type in a Roman Numeral")

i=0
ouput=0

for i in range(0, len(UserInput)):
    i = i + 1

    if len(UserInput) == 1:
        print((DictOfRomanNumerals[UserInput[0]]))
    else:
        if len(UserInput) > 1:
```

Comment: What did you intend to put after `if len(UserInput) > 1:`? Were you planning to use `i` in any way (hint)?

Comment: What is the procedure *you* would use to convert a given roman numeral to the integer it represents?  That's a good place to start in figuring out how to tell a computer how to do it.

Comment: Is the dictionary something that you had to use, or is it your own idea?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, create some possible numerals and their values and some special values like 4, 9, 40, 90, 400, 900. Now scan the given string, if some substring is present in the table, then take its value into result, then check for the next, for next match, it adds the value with the result, finally forms the number.

```
roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}
          s = input("Type in a Roman Numeral")
          i = 0
          num = 0
          while i < len(s):
             if i+1<len(s) and s[i:i+2] in roman:
                num+=roman[s[i:i+2]]
                i+=2
             else:
                #print(i)
                num+=roman[s[i]]
                i+=1
          print(num)
```

Comment: Just dumping code without any explanation what you changed and why you changed it seldom helps.

Comment: Emily, if this works for you, would you mark my answer and upvote